# Reminder Email User for Password Expiration in AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES to send mail from my website (Using Laravel). 
I want to set password expiry reminder before expiring (SES) password.

I have gone through some articles and documentation but did not get any solution.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=279199